# Connection to mongoDB via SSH golang

Tags: go, ssh, mgo

I need to connect to remote mongoDB server via ssh, i was doing this earlier with mysql and its looks like :

```
sshcon, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", sshHost, sshPort), sshConfig)
    if err == nil {
        defer sshcon.Close()
        mysql.RegisterDial("mysql+tcp", (&ViaSSHDialer{sshcon}).Dial)
```

Is there a similar function like mysql.RegisterDial in mgo package?

Comment: Do you need to tunnel or are you just trying to have a poor man's version of TLS?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I need to tunnel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really does not make sense to add the tunneling function into your code. A simple wrapper shell script prevents you from the necessity to reinvent the wheel:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

ssh $USER@$MONGO_HOST -L $LOCAL_PORT:127.0.0.1:27017
./yourApplication "$*"
```

With this, you can call your program via the wrapper as usual.